# Upgrading WebMatrix to V3

Tags: upgrade, webmatrix

Just upgraded WebMatrix this morning to WebMatrix V3, but now when I open the solution in Visual Studio, it displays the error "the selected file is not a valid solution file".

Everything was working fine before the upgrade!

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Worked it out - if you remove the old solution file (backing it up first), then click the "Visual Studio Launch" icon in WebMatrix, the solution file is recreated for you.